# How do I prove that $(x^2)f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is the Dirichlet function, is nowhere derivable function other than $x = 0$

Tags: calculus

How do I prove that $(x^2)f(x)$ is nowhere derivable other than $x = 0$, when $f(x)$ is the Dirichlet function?

Comment: By using the defintion of "derivative" and "differentiable", presumably. What's stopping you?

Comment: Do you mean *differentiable* rather than derivable? If so, you should probably edit your post for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @ThePointer Actually "derivable" is a fairly common synonym around here; I  conjecture that comes from typical use in some language or other...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Hmm, "around here" being Europe?

Comment: @ThePointer No, by "around here" I meant "on MSE"...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ahh, ok. I've never seen it used in this way on MSE, so I didn't even occur to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g(x) = x^2f(x)$ was differentiable at $x_0 \neq 0$, then so would be $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x^2}$ at $x_0$ as the quotient of two differentiable maps is differentiable if the denominator is not vanishing at the point considered. Which is not the case as $f$ is not even continuous.

Now you have for $x \neq 0$
$$\left\vert \frac{g(x)}{x} \right\vert \le \vert x \vert,$$ proving that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ with $g^\prime(x)=0$.